# c++ debug break exception

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, breakpoints

I'm using visual studio to code in C++

I have the following code

```
// fondamentaux C++.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{//initialisation des variables

        int total{ 0 };
        int tab[5]{ 11,22,33,44 };

//on double la valeur de l'index pour additionner les valeurs entre elles

(*tab) = 2;

//boucle pour additionner les valeurs entre elles
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(tab); i++)
        {
            total += *(tab + i);
        }

//libérationn de l'espace mémoire
        delete[] tab;
        *tab = 0;


//affichage du total
        cout << "total = " << total << "\n"; // le total est 121
        return 0;
}
```

In theory everything should work but when I try to launch with the local debugger [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djmsZ.png)

How do I debug it?

Comment: You only `delete` what you `new`, so `delete[] tab;` is incorrect.

Comment: Also, step into your program or set a breakpoint on the first line, then step line by line until you see the problem.

Comment: thanks it worked ;)

Comment: Always look in the Output window when you get an unexpected breakpoint like that.  You will no doubt see a message from the Debug Heap, telling you about the UB in your code.

Comment: @Zatharan, like crashmstr and Nikolay Jambazov's suggestion, it would be related to your code,  you can call delete for data when you allocate the memory using new. Nikolay Jambazov posted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'tab' pointer points to memory allocated in the stack not in the heap, so memory will be freed automatically after function exit. Calling of

```
delete[] tab;
```

is wrong. No need to call it, memory will be automatically freed.

```
*tab = 0;
```

is wrong too, because defined that way, the pointer is 'const'.
If you want to allocate memory in heap you should do:

```
int* tab = new int[5]{ 11,22,33,44 };
```

and rest of your code will work.